# What are the optimal data structures for implementing a hidden layer neural network with backpropagation in C++?

Tags: c++, data-structures, neural-network, linked-list, backpropagation

Apologies if this seems like a duplicate post, but I am wondering what the optimal data structures for implementing and storing a simple hidden layer neural network with weights and biases and backpropagation in C++ are.

Off the top of my head I was thinking about the following:

- Linked list
- Pointer array

These two seem mostly equivalent to me for this purpose.
I also often see people using 3D arrays/vectors to store the weights and biases, but this seems wasteful to me, since you're either limited to a neural network that has the same number of nodes at each layer, or you're storing a lot of zero-entries in your 3D array for node connections that don't exist.

Comment: Does the number of a) the nodes and b) the number of outgoing edges per node change after construction?

Comment: What would the linked list hold? What would the pointers in the pointer array point at?

Comment: `"arrays/vectors to store the weights and biases [...] seems wasteful to me"` - actually it's the optimal choice, and it does not at all restrict the size of your layers. I suggest you look into fully-connected layers represented as matrix multiplication and you'll begin to see why.

Comment: @bitmask for simplicity I would assume the number of nodes and edges to remain fixed.

Comment: @PeteBecker each node of the linked list would hold the bias vector and the 2D connection weight matrix of each neural network layer.

Comment: @alter_igel I fully agree on the matrix multiplication statement. My question was rather, what kind of data structure the 2D layer matrices would be stored in. Many codes I have seen use 3D arrays to store the 2D matrices, so for a neural network with a maximum node number of 'n' and 'k' layers, they would store the neural network in a k x n x n array, for example.

Comment: Honestly that depends on how you would like to work. If you like to be explicit, you could store all layers simply as fields of a struct and invoke them one after the other. Otherwise, you could define a struct interface for each layer with e.g. `std::vector<double> apply(const std::vector<double>& inputs) const;` which would allow you to loop over e.g. a vector of layers, passing previous outputs as inputs to the current layer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option I see is doing it like this: Have one linear array for the nodes and one for all the edges. A sketch:

```
struct Node {
  std::size_t edgeBegin;
  std::size_t edgeEnd;
};
struct Edge {
  std::size_t to;
  float weight;
};
struct Layer {
  std::size_t layerBegin;
  std::size_t layerEnd;
};
struct Network {
  std::vector<Node> nodes;
  std::vector<Edge> edges;
  std::array<Layer,3> layers;
};
```

after populating this structure it might look like this:

```
nodes:  [n0, n1, n2, n3, n4, n5, n6, n7]
layers: [(0, 2), (2, 5), (5, 8)]
-> input layer has two nodes, hidden has three, output layer has three
```

where each node points to a section in edges, holding the edges of that particular node.

By doing it like this, you have a high chance to be cache-local **and** you only have to request dynamic memory twice if you set up the initialisation of the network correctly.

This assumes that the network will not change (i.e. new nodes being created while using it, and no new edges being created).

Comment: Nice, thank you. I would have included the edges as a matrix in the layer struct.